# MSI Patch Creation Problems

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, windows-installer, setup-project, patch

A new version of our product (a software package) has been released recently. To expand functionality, we developed a plugin afterwards. Now we would like to deploy these files (two new files and an updated version of an existing file) as hotfix (or update) with MSI patch (msp). I downloaded a blank PCP file from MSDN website and made some changes in it. The changes involve the following tables:

ImageFamilies

PatchMetadata

PatchSequence

Properties

TargetImages

UpgradedImages

All the other tables remain blank.

Then, I managed to create an msp file with this PCP file based on two versions of the admin image of the software package, both of which were built from Visual Studio setup project (VS 2010). The difference between these two msi packages are that I replaced a file and added two new files in, but nothing else. I didn't change the product code (GUID), the upgrade code (GUID), nor the version number.

Then I was trying to install this msp file on top of the released version.

1. The first screen appearing is asking to Repair or Remove the product. This is not what we want. We want the installer is like a fresh installation, including showing the licence agreement. How do I define the UI for MSI patch?
2. During the installation of the patch, I got an error message as below, then the installation failed:

   `Error 1001. Exception occurred while initializing the installation: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\WINDOWS\system32\Files\BPS\TestApp' or one of its dependencies. This system cannot find the file specified.`

   BPS is the folder where we install our product in [ProgramFilesFolder]. I wondered why MSI was trying to search in "C:\Windows\system32" for files installed in [ProgramFilesFolder]. In addition, the changed files in the hotfix are located in somewhere else ([CommonAppDataFolder]) instead of in this "BPS" folder.

Can anyone help me with these problems? If any more information is needed to identify the issues, please let me know. Any thoughts, advices, suggestions would be very much appreciated.

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The first screen appearing is asking
>   to Repair or Remove the product. This
>   is not what we want.

In the upgrade package increase the Product Version. This way you will use a [minor upgrade](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370037%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead of a small update.

You can also try using the MSIEXEC command line to apply the patch:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367574(VS.85).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367575(VS.85).aspx

> During the installation of the patch,
>   I got an error message as below, then
>   the installation failed

Is there something in your installer using that file? Perhaps a custom action? Try looking in the log to see what action tries to access that file.

Comment: We really want to use small update as opposed to minor upgrade because nothing has been changed in terms of the whole application but adding a couple of new files which are not part of the main app at all.

I tried to apply the patch with the MSIEXEC command line as below:

`msiexec /p patch.msp REINSTALL=DefaultFeature REINSTALLMODE=omus`

I was still asked to "Repair" or "Remove" the product.


We did have some custom action living in the main executable which is located in the "[ProgramFilesFolder]\BPS\TestApp". 

(Continuing in the following comment)...

Comment: I had no idea why MSI was trying to find the file from this folder. Below is the related log info which is a part of the whole file:

`MSI (s) (CC!84) [06:54:28:815]: ǜǜ朁㿟ǜǜǜǜ栗㿟⃰㿾ǜ枸㿟鶠ﰜǜ䎇㿥鶠ﰐ䎫㿥鶠ǜĀ
DEBUG: Error 2769:  Custom Action _033C6FDE_163D_4E6F_AC4A_4B229C2D9DF2.install did not close 1 MSIHANDLEs.
The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2769. The arguments are: _033C6FDE_163D_4E6F_AC4A_4B229C2D9DF2.install, 1, 
`

NOTE: I don't know what the above strange characters are.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, Cosmin Pirvu. I should have put this line to the top of my first comment. But I was not allowed to change it.

Comment: You can add a /qb to your command line so the patch is applied without prompting for repair. Also, make sure that your feature ID is enclosed in quotes: REINSTALL="DefaultFeature". Regarding the custom action, make sure that in the upgraded package it uses this condition: (NOT Installed).

Comment: Brilliant, that works very well. But I had a problem when trying to uninstall this update from "Add or Remove Programs". I got the same error as what I got before. I have a custom actions which is supposed to run when unistall the whole software. I put "NOT REMOVE" as condition against this custom action in VS setup. But it doesn't work. What condition should I put in this case? I **DON'T** want the custom action to run when uninstall the patch update.

Comment: Did you try setting the custom action condition to (NOT Installed)?

Comment: Yes, I did. But again, it was working fine when installing the patch update, got an error when uninstall it. I also tried "NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH", "NOT Installed AND NOT PATCH AND NOT REMOVE". Any ideas?

Comment: Most likely it's affected by the old package configuration. If the custom action didn't have a condition in the old version, it may run during uninstall. In this case you would need to first fix the condition in your old MSI, recache it on the target machine and only then apply the patch. Perhaps this will help with the recache: http://setupanddeployment.com/cleanup/installer-cleanup/